# Extracting img from url - Script works in jsfiddle, but not on my site, can anyone spot the reason why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Disclaimer:  I'm about green as they get working with javascript:

So anyway, after much trial and error, and probably butchering this code, I've finally managed to enable auto embedding of media on my forum.  I'm using oembed, and then a script for images and attachments.  One problem though:

http://jsfiddle.net/khb8g6e3/

This one works on jsfiddle, but not on my site (using the same source code)
Here's the source
(not enough reputation points to post link, I'll try to add after).

My first attempt was this:

http://jsfiddle.net/edhg1zu0/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var href = $('a.postlink.img-link').get(0).href;
$('a.postlink.img-link').html($('<img>').attr('src', href));
$('a.postlink.img-link').colorbox({
        scalePhotos:'true',
        maxHeight:'99%',
        maxWidth:'99%',
        opacity:'0.75',
        fixed:true,
        photo:true
    });
```

})

Which works, but only shows one image over and over again.

I'd be happy with either code(whichever is easiest to fix), if someone could show me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Here's my site where the first code doesn't work.  https://raiderforums.com/viewtopic.php?p=333773#p333773

Comment: Thanks Alon, it seems to break the images when I add that  http://jsfiddle.net/7ug42pn9/

Comment: I removed my comment because I think @Scott's answer is the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to work properly I had to remove the colorbox code because it was throwing js errors.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a.postlink.img-link').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).append('<img src="'+href+'">');   
  }) 
})
```

You can see it functioning here: http://jsfiddle.net/edhg1zu0/1/

Comment: p.s. this place won't let me give you reputation for it because I'm not important enough.  Sorry Scott, maybe someone else will be nice and give you a bump for me.

Comment: No worries. It's the thought that counts. Right ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess without looking at the actual code, but does your actual page have more than one target element with the class img-link? If so you may need to loop through each element.

```
$('a.postlink.img-link').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).get(0).href;
  $(this).html($('<img>').attr('src', href));
  $(this).colorbox({
        scalePhotos:'true',
        maxHeight:'99%',
        maxWidth:'99%',
        opacity:'0.75',
        fixed:true,
        photo:true
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you're correct, but shouldn't you use `$(this)` inside the `each` loop to get the current element? In your answer, you always referencing to the first element in the collection

Comment: You are correct, sorry, sometimes editing code on mobile isn't always easy. I edited my answer.

Comment: How about a selected answer too :)

Comment: Scott's answer only shows one image, I get a link for the 2nd.  http://jsfiddle.net/51nbjL21/

Comment: Don't leave me now! lol...I'll keep trying, hope you guys come back.

Comment: @corleoner Nobody is leaving you - Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/51nbjL21/1/ The reason your's didin't worked is because of a JS error that the script of `colorbox` function doesn't exists in the fiddle so it break the loop after the first image.

Comment: Thanks Alon, I'll stop being a big baby now :)